# Elasticsearch Bulk API using curl and text file

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a beginner with Elasticsearch and am following an "Essential Training" in LinkedIn Learning. I'm trying to follow with bulk loading API and the instructor is using Linux, I'm on Windows. He created a text file to read in with data using "VI". I just created a text file and pasted the data and removed the ".txt". The contents of the file, called reqs, is this:

```json
{
   "index":{
      "_index":"my-test",
      "_type":"my-type",
      "_id":"1"
   }
}{
   "col1":"val1"
}{
   "index":{
      "_index":"my-test",
      "_type":"my-type",
      "_id":"2"
   }
}{
   "col1":"val2"
}{
   "index":{
      "_index":"my-test",
      "_type":"my-type",
      "_id":"3"
   }
}{
   "col1":"val3"
}
```

I've tried saving it with a carriage return (new line) after the last line and without. I saved this into my elasticsearch folder (C:\elasticsearch-7.12.0) which is the same directory I'm running the following command from:

```
c:\elasticsearch-7.12.0>curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@reqs"; echo
```

When I do this, I'm getting the following error:

```json
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"},"status":400}
```

Comment: The `application/x-ndjson` format is newline-delimited JSON. I'm pretty sure the formatted JSON file will not work. Maybe ensure each document is on a separate line, no newlines for human-friendly formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Use this below curl command

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index-name/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @reqs.json
```

`reqs.json` should look like this

```
{"index" : {"_index" : "my-test", "_type" : "my-type", "_id" : "1"}}
{"col1" : "val1"}
{"index" : {"_index" : "my-test", "_type" : "my-type", "_id" : "2"}}
{"col1" : "val2"}
{"index" : {"_index" : "my-test", "_type" : "my-type", "_id" : "3"}}
{"col1" : "val3"}
```

Comment: I am SO sorry - I thought I had posted a reply (NEW to Stack Overflow). It didn't work - I got a {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"},"status":400}

Comment: @Rob Searing have you saved the file in `.json` format ? i.e instead of just `reqs`, you need to save it as `reqs.json`

Comment: correct. I have elasticsearch and kibana both working (when I open a browser I can get localhost:9200 & :5601 - Kibana opens). I have reqs.json in the elasticsearch folder with contents:

{"index" : {"_index" : "my-test", "_type" : "my-type", "_id" : "1"}}
{"col1" : "val1"}
{"index" : {"_index" : "my-test", "_type" : "my-type", "_id" : "2"}}
{"col1" : "val2"}
{"index" : {"_index" : "my-test", "_type" : "my-type", "_id" : "3"}}
{"col1" : "val3"}

I copy paste your curl command from the same folder I have the reqs.json file in (the elasticsearch one) and get

Comment: c:\elasticsearch-7.12.0>curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index-name/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @reqs.json
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'localhost